# How to (correctly) manage utf-8 in bibliographic references

Tags: bibliographies

users,

I have a persistent problem when I try to construct bibliographic references using 'exotic' accents. An example is provided below, with the error message. I am aware that this is a known problem, but I don't understand what the core of the problem is (I just suppose that it has something to do with multibyte segmentation) and, anyway, I just found some hints at rather cryptic workarounds.
Anticipated thanks for enlightening me.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

On this notion see the work of Búbür (2009).  \\\  
On this notion see \cite{Búbür2009}.

\begin{thebibliography}{widestlabel}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Búbür}{Búbür}{2009}]{Búbür2009}
\newblock Búbür, Bub (2009).
\newblock A theory of everything plus something else.
\newblock \textit{Journal of Unfocusing} 12, pp.\ 22-39.


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

pdflatex loudly complains as soon as it sees the first accented u:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \IeC 
l.21 ...year{Búbür}{Búbür}{2009}]{Búbür2009}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \IeC 
l.21 ...year{Búbür}{Búbür}{2009}]{Búbür2009}
```

A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The error is in using accents in the key, which is just an arbitrary label; use `\cite{bubur2009}` and change the key in the bib file.

Answer (score 5):

From [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex):

> BibTeX it­self is an ASCII-only pro­gram; there is, how­ever, a
>   ver­sion that copes with 8-bit char­ac­ter sets. How­ever, BibTeX’s
>   fa­cil­i­ties rapidly run out as one moves away from sim­ple ASCII
>   (for ex­am­ple, in the var­i­ous na­tional sort­ing rules for
>   lan­guages ex­pressed in dif­fer­ent parts of ISO-8859 — the “ISO
>   Latin” se­ries). For more flex­i­bil­ity, the user is urged to
>   con­sider us­ing `biber` with `bibla­tex` to type­set its out­put. In
>   par­tic­u­lar, it is best to avoid BibTeX in favour of `bibla­tex`, if
>   at all pos­si­ble.